# Can a proper subspace of a Banach space be a countable intersection of open sets?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, baire-category

*Let X be a Banach space and suppose E is a dense linear subspace
which is a Gδ -set. Show that E = X.*

By the Baire Category theorem we can show that *E* is non-meager (second category), but I don't know where to continue from here. If I could show that every proper subspace is meager, then I would be done, but I don't know if this is the correct approach.

Comment: The real line is a countable intersection of open sets in the plane.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3188/are-proper-linear-subspaces-of-banach-spaces-always-meager) may help.

Comment: Very nice question. That is wrong if sets are closed instead open.